# Como evitar problemas de encoding quando pega dados com TwitteR?

Tags: r, ascii, utf-8, twitter-api, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou pegando dados do Twitter com o pacote `twitteR` para [r](/questions/tagged/r) mas os tweets estão vindo com problema de *encoding*. Alguém sabe contornar esse problema?

```
library(twitteR)
library(stringr)
library(ROAuth)
library(RCurl)

options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))


setwd("XXXXXXXXX")

download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",destfile="cacert.pem")

cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                         consumerSecret='XXXXXXXXXXXX',
                         requestURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
                         accessURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
                         authURL='http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize')

cred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")

registerTwitterOAuth(cred)

tweets = searchTwitter("#Copa2014", n=200, cainfo="cacert.pem")

Tweets.text = laply(tweets,function(t)t$getText())
```

Os dados estão vindo dessa maneira, com problemas em acentos e cedilhas:

```
head(Tweets.text)
[1] "NÃ£o fui sorteado dessa vez, mas dia 12/03 comeÃ§a uma nova fase de vendas... #copa2014"                                                       
[2] "RT @obsate: @RodP13 @gugakuerten A #Copa2014 virou a Geni; todo mundo bate nela. Agora a copa tem de resolver todos os problemas do BR. Piaâ€¦"
[3] "@RodP13 @gugakuerten A #Copa2014 virou a Geni; todo mundo bate nela. Agora a copa tem de resolver todos os problemas do BR. Piada!"            
[4] "Nem pra saude! \"@mordomoeugenio: BilhÃ£o de reais pra ensino pÃºblico nÃ£o tem nÃ© #copa2014 #JN\""                                           
[5] "RT @soldadonofront: \"@fsouzajrJuca: Quanto mais eu leio sobre esses grupos que protestam contra a Copa, mais eu simpatizo com a #Copa2014.\"" 
[6] "\"@fsouzajrJuca: Quanto mais eu leio sobre esses grupos que protestam contra a Copa, mais eu simpatizo com a #Copa2014.\""
```

Estou usando:

> Rstudio 0.98.501
>   R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

PS: O problema aparentemente está ocorrendo no Windows 7. Seguindo as instruções do Luis Cipriani e rodando o código no Linux, não houve problemas de encoding. A pergunta ainda permance para evitar os problemas no Windows,

Comment: Essa pergunta é boa e bastante útil. Ninguém?

Comment: Tá com cara que vem em UTF-8 e em algum erro da biblioteca ou do programa está codificando uma segunda vez. Erro infelizmente comum no Python :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se há como resolver permanentemente os problemas de codificação de caracteres. Há vários fatores que atrapalham a identificação correta do encoding. Numa determinada página da internet, a codificação informada ao navegador na tag META (dentro da seção HEAD) pode não ser a codificação efetivamente utilizada; há ainda as configurações locais do seu computador; a codificação que foi definida como default dentro do R, etc.

A dica geral é a seguinte: textos em português geralmente estão codificados como "latin1" ou "latin2". Então é possível testar algumas conversões entre sistemas de codificação.

Veja um exemplo utilizando seus dados:

```
    tweets <- c("NÃ£o fui sorteado dessa vez, mas dia 12/03 comeÃ§a uma nova fase de vendas... #copa2014",
    "RT @obsate: @RodP13 @gugakuerten A #Copa2014 virou a Geni; todo mundo bate nela. Agora a copa tem de resolver todos os problemas do BR. Piaâ€¦",
    "@RodP13 @gugakuerten A #Copa2014 virou a Geni; todo mundo bate nela. Agora a copa tem de resolver todos os problemas do BR. Piada!",
    "Nem pra saude! \"@mordomoeugenio: BilhÃ£o de reais pra ensino pÃºblico nÃ£o tem nÃ© #copa2014 #JN\"",
    "RT @soldadonofront: \"@fsouzajrJuca: Quanto mais eu leio sobre esses grupos que protestam contra a Copa, mais eu simpatizo com a #Copa2014.\"",
    "\"@fsouzajrJuca: Quanto mais eu leio sobre esses grupos que protestam contra a Copa, mais eu simpatizo com a #Copa2014.\"")
```

Agora executo o seguinte:

```
    iconv(tweets, from="UTF-8", to="latin1//TRANSLIT")
```

E obtenho:

```
    [1] "Não fui sorteado dessa vez, mas dia 12/03 começa uma nova fase de vendas... #copa2014"                                                        
    [2] "RT @obsate: @RodP13 @gugakuerten A #Copa2014 virou a Geni; todo mundo bate nela. Agora a copa tem de resolver todos os problemas do BR. Pia." 
    [3] "@RodP13 @gugakuerten A #Copa2014 virou a Geni; todo mundo bate nela. Agora a copa tem de resolver todos os problemas do BR. Piada!"           
    [4] "Nem pra saude! \"@mordomoeugenio: Bilhão de reais pra ensino público não tem né #copa2014 #JN\""                                              
    [5] "RT @soldadonofront: \"@fsouzajrJuca: Quanto mais eu leio sobre esses grupos que protestam contra a Copa, mais eu simpatizo com a #Copa2014.\""
    [6] "\"@fsouzajrJuca: Quanto mais eu leio sobre esses grupos que protestam contra a Copa, mais eu simpatizo com a #Copa2014.\""
```

Deu certo.

Outras opções para teste poderiam ser:

```
    iconv(tweets, from="UTF-8", to="latin2//TRANSLIT")
    iconv(tweets, from="UTF-8", to="latin1")
    iconv(tweets, from="UTF-8", to="latin2")
```

Ajudei?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, eu rodei o seu código na seguinte configuração:

```
RStudio: 0.98.501
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
platform: Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 (Mac)
Versões das bibliotecas:
    twitteR 1.1.7 (from CRAN)
    stringr 0.6.2
    ROauth 0.9.3
    RCurl 1.95-4.1
    rjson 0.2.13
```

E o resultado foi:

```
> tweets
[[1]]
[1] "sigaCopa2014: 11h10. Arena da Baixada terá evento-teste em março - Via Portal 2014 http://t.co/GmhnF87ji2 #copa2014"

[[2]]
[1] "_copadomundo_: #futebol #copa2014 Eto'o ironiza boatos sobre sua idade usando seus gols no Chelsea como argumento: Gazeta Ata... http://t.co/4YkV7g1Wgv"

[[3]]
[1] "_copadomundo_: #futebol #copa2014 Apesar de empate, Renato Gaúcho aprova quarteto ofensivo do Fluminense: Gazeta Flu encarou ... http://t.co/Co0MmJCEC1"
```

Veja que os acentos estão ok, portanto, não me parece ser um problema do TwitteR. Poderia enviar suas versões de libs?

Comment: As minhas versões das library são as mesmas que as tuas. A única diferença que vejo é no sistema operacional (estou usando Windows). Será que pode ser por causa disso? Vou tentar no Ubuntu quando tiver tempo.

Comment: Sim, pode ser. O ruim de problemas de encoding é que eles podem acontecer em diversas camadas entre o sistema operacional e o sua aplicação.

Comment: Funcionou no Ubuntu 12.04.2. Vou editar a pergunta mencionando que no ubuntu funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Lidei com esta mesma situação e descobri que trata-se de **Double Enconding**.
Então basta retirá-lo abrindo **duas** vezes e depois trazendo **de volta** para o formato *ideal*.

#### PROBLEMA: DOUBLE ENCODING

```
campo1_txt = iconv(Tweets.text, to="latin1", from="utf-8")
```

#### CORRIJO COM DOUBLE-DECODING

```
campo1_txt = iconv(campo1_txt, to="latin1", from="utf-8")
```

#### RECODE PARA FICAR COM A INFORMAÃÃO CORRETA

```
campo1_txt = iconv(campo1_txt, to="UTF-8", from="latin1")
```

A partir deste ponto pode prosseguir normalmente pois funcionará.