# Caracteres KWIC Quanteda

Tags: r, text

Olá 
Estou utilizando R junto com Quanteda para fazer o levantamento de KWIC em um corpus da agência Lupa. Estou com problemas nos caracteres.

Faço a importação do corpus da seguinte forma:

```
corpus.fake.df <- readtext("../dados/analise/*.txt",
                      docvarsfrom = "filenames",
                      encoding = "UTF-8")
fake.corpus <- corpus(corpus.fake.df)
```

Após feito isso, rodo uma kwic com um termo:

```
k <- kwic(fake.tokens , "gomes", 5, case_insensitive=TRUE, encTo = "UTF-8", valuetype = "regex")
```

Ao pedir para visualizar os dados, ao invés de chamar o visualizador do Rstudio, o que tenho é um janela do navegador, com os caracteres todos errados:

[image: Janela com o erro]

Muito obrigado!

Comment: o problema está na `corpus.fake.df` e não na função `kwid`.
Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6805/como-evitar-problemas-de-encoding-quando-pega-dados-com-twitter,

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!. Não consegui, tentei e deu o mesmo problema

Comment: Você já tentou `encTo='windows1252'` ou `encTo="latin1"`?

Comment: Já sim, infelizmente não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Posteriormente consegui resolver a questão instalando um pacote chamado [DT](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DT/index.html) no [R](https://www.r-project.org/). No caso do problema que relatei acima, ao ser utilizando em conjunto com o pacote [Quanteda](https://quanteda.io/) no  [Rstudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) gera um visualização bem amigável, com acentos corretos e capaz de ser exportada para HTML para edição posterior.

Valeu!